# A country with dual payment system

Tags: currency, banking, money

Is there any country with dual domestic payment system?

For instance, in the USA there are CHIPS or Fedwire both help wire transfer of USD within the USA. They give services to international organizations but these organizations have an account with an American Financial Institution.

In my case, I ask if country A using currency A as legal tender issued by its own central bank IS ALSO using other countries currencies in domestic wire transfer system? That means that country A will not need to use SWIFT for the other countries currencies.

Your input whether such a case is applicable or not is also appreciated.